# Wordpress Disabling Fullscreen Mode from Embedded Vimeo Videos

Tags: wordpress, embed, vimeo, vimeo-player

I have used Wordpress since 2014 and Vimeo to embed videos for a long time as well. I use the classic WordPress editor by using the plugin "Classic Editor". (I have tried the block editor a few times and it's just terrible).

Recently I have been embedding more videos and I noticed the fullscreen option was "disappearing" after I embed.

Here is a post that has the problem on two videos. The videos on this post should have a little fullscreen button but they don't:
https://timev3technology.com/job6/

Vimeo provides embed code that includes a fullscreen option:
`allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture"`

This is the full embed code straight from Vimeo before I paste it into the WordPress post:
`<div style="padding:100% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/886704254?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;quality_selector=1&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="Job 6 - Cannon Pinion Removal with Horotec Watch Hand Removing Press"></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>`

As you can see from that, the fullscreen option should be enabled.

I emailed Vimeo's customer support and they pointed out that my site includes somewhere in the HTML:
`class="player player-2930086a-90c0-457c-ab75-79180bc27cce js-player-fullscreen with-fullscreen with-sticky-custom-logo player-normal player-xs app-xs no-fullscreen-support"`

I don't know if that `no-fullscree-support` is causing the problem but it seems like it might be. You can see that code snippet by going to my post (https://timev3technology.com/job6/) and Ctrl+Shift+I the page and search the HTML for 'fullscreen'.

I have not changed anything yet because I like to use WordPress and Vimeo "out of the box" because I'm not trying to code my whole site, but it seems like in this case WordPress is actively recognizing a video and disabling the fullscreen option. Maybe if I can just disable that "feature" of WordPress somehow the Vimeo embed code can be left alone to do its job? I don't know how to do that though. Anybody?

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. Vimeo's old embed code that I had used on my old videos used a different code to allow the fullscreen button.

Old code that worked within the embed code:
`allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"`

I just added that code to the embed code and unlike the new standard Vimeo code, WordPress didn't mess with it and fullscreen is enabled.